# Exporting excel from salesforce

Tags: visualforce

Hi I have created form which has an excel template for users to download and fill, but when i click on download link its getting redirected to another page.I dont know how to proceed and I want to remain on same page and hold the filled information. pls help me out!!
The excel headers are in a VF page Template

```
<apex:outputLink value="{! $Page.Template}" rendered="null"> Download </apex:outputLink> 
<br/><br/>

public ExportToExcel() {
   //Apex Page refference methods from apex can used to redirect from one page to another page.
     public ApexPages.PageReference goToExportPage() {
        return Page.Template;
     } 

<apex:page showHeader="false" controller="ExportToExcel" ContentType="application/vnd.ms-excel#Report.xls" standardstylesheets="false" cache="True" > 
 <apex:panelGrid border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5"/> 
   <head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" /> 
    <style type="text/css"> 
       table, th, td { border: .5px solid black; } 
       tr{ border: .5px solid black;} 
    </style> 
  </head> 
  <body>
     <table> 
       <tr> 
        <th filter="all">Unit</th>
  </body>
```

Comment: Can you share you visualforce page code?

Answer (score 2):

Use commandLink tag and action attribute to call goToExportPage() method.

`<apex:commandLink id="exportlink" action="{!goToExportPage}" value="{!$Page.Template"} />`

Answer (score -2):

[Visualforce Export Excel Report Using Remote Action and AlaSQL](https://nitinkhunalsalesforce.wordpress.com/2016/10/27/visualforce-export-excel-report-using-remote-action-and-alasql/)

You can export excel using javascript remoting, For this you don't need to create additional visualforce page to renderAs excel.